# Find link URL in string not image

Tags: php, string, image, url, text

I am trying to find a URL in a String not from `<img>`. For example:

```
$string = "lorem ipsum http://google.com dolor sit amet <img src="http://img.com/img.png" />;
```

To:

lorem ipsum http://google.com dolor sit amet 
< img src="http://img.com/img.png" / >

I tried this:

```
function make_clickable($text) {
$regex = '#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#';
return preg_replace_callback($regex, function ($matches) {
    return "<p><a href='{$matches[0]}' class='link'>{$matches[0]}</a></p>";
}, $text);
$matches = array();
```

}

Editor:
So could this:

```
function make_clickable($text) {
 $regex = '#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#';
 return preg_replace_callback($regex, function ($matches) {
    return "<p><a href='{$matches[0]}' class='link'>{$matches[0]}</a></p>";
 }, $text);
 $matches = array();
}

$string = preg_replace('/\bsrc="http\b/u', 'src="htt-p', $string);
$string = make_clickable($string);
$string = preg_replace('/\bsrc="htt-p\b/u', 'src="http', $string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it. Short explanations on how it works can be found in the codes comments:

```
<?php

# fixed syntax error string
$string = "lorem ipsum http://google.com dolor sit amet <img src=\"http://img.com/img.png\" />";

function make_clickable($text) {
    # explode string on spaces to array
    $arr = explode(' ', $text);

    # test each array element if it contains nothing else but a website
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if(preg_match('#((^https?|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))([\s)\[\]{},;"\':<]|\.\s|$)#i', $value)){
            # replace plain text urls with href links in array
            $arr[$key] = "<p><a href='". $value ."' class='link'>". $value ."</a></p>";
        }
    }

    # rebuild array back to string
    $text = implode(' ', $arr);

    # return result
    return $text;
}

echo make_clickable($string);

?>
```

Comment: @neryaelul The code works fine. I've tested it myself. Run it in a seperate file and you'll see it works. So something else must be wrong on your side.

Comment: @neryaelul The backslash in the image code is a php escape character to prevent the string from terminating to soon. It won't be included in the output. But you can always just replace it with `$string = 'lorem ipsum http://google.com dolor sit amet <img src="http://img.com/img.png" />';`